# Autoit controls

Tags: bots, autoit

I use [`ControlSend()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) to send hotkeys in a different window. Problem is to find the right window control. Or the control is right and there is an unknown issue. These are the controls:

> **Title**: PokeMMO
>   **Class**: LWJGL
>   **controlID**: still unknown
>   **Process**: javaw.exe

```
$handle = WinGetHandle("[TITLE:PokeMMO; CLASS:LWJGL]")
ControlSend($handle, Default, $handle, "{Down}")
```

Didn't work.

```
Global $sProcess = "javaw.exe" ; Process PokeMMO 

ControlSend(_Process2Win($sProcess), "", "", "{DOWN}")

Func _Process2Win($pid)
    If IsString($pid) Then $pid = ProcessExists($pid)
    If $pid = 0 Then Return -1
    $list = WinList()
    For $i = 1 To $list[0][0]
        If $list[$i][0] <> "" And BitAND(WinGetState($list[$i][1]), 2) Then
            $wpid = WinGetProcess($list[$i][0])
            If $wpid = $pid Then Return $list[$i][0]
        EndIf
    Next
    Return -1
EndFunc   ;==>_Process2Win
```

Didn't work. I also tried this:

```
Run("C:\path\path\path\PokeMMO.exe")
WinWait("[CLASS:LWJGL]")
Local $sControl = ControlGetFocus("[CLASS:LWJGL]")
MsgBox(0, "ControlGetFocus Example", "The control that has focus is: " & $sControl)
```

> Stystem Message: Java Virtual Machine Launcher - A Java Exception has occured ERROR!

[A guide on YouTube](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) tells to install a different version of Java.

Comment: Is it a desktop window? Try to WinFlash it. Is it an exe-compiled Java program? Java doesn't use the native Win API. So it's hard to automate. Try to change the Default parameter in the first example with an empty String "". If Control-Functions don't work with the Java application, you should try to use WinActivate and then just Send.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Title and text parameter, but leave the controlID parameter free like "" or  ''. That should also work. Good luck.